# How does an ohmmeter measure different resistances?

Tags: ohmmeter

An ohmmeter has set of range settings for the resistances to be measured.
When we switch to any range, what behavior of the test reference is being adjusted?

In other words; I'm wondering if we change lets say from a 200 to 1k ohm range, what exactly are we changing? Are we adjusting the voltage applied to the resistance under test or are we adjusting the current flowing through the resistance under test?

(If we want to measure a diode's bulk resistance I may need to know what is applied to the ends of the diode not to damage it)

Comment: We're only adjusting the *resistance* of one part of a voltage divider. So in an open circuit condition, like a reversed diode, the full voltage of the measuring circuit is across the diode. This may be the supply voltage of the meter, e.g. 5V, 4.5V, 6V or something else. The current used for the measurement should be neglible, i.e. micro-amps or low milli-amps. Hard to damage something by that *current*.

Comment: the text Im reading recommends to use the high resistance settings of an ohmmeter when checking diodes. what could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the meter uses a different reference resistor for each range.

These could be built with (say) 100 ohm + 900 + 9k + 90k +900k + 9M in series. Starting from the 100 ohm, each tap point gives a total of 100, 1k, 10k etc. The ADC converter in a meter actually measures the ratio of two values -- usually an unknown input voltage and known reference voltage. Either of these can be varied.

So, if you connect the above R string in series with the unknown resistor and pass *any* current through it, the ratio of the voltage across the unknown R and the known reference R will equal the resistor ratios. The ADC just displays this (scaled) ratio.

So, most meters apply about 1-3 V across that whole string and display the result.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiAuPd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here, depending on which switch is closed, the meter will be on a different range. Some current will flow through the whole string; the voltage across the upper portion will generate the reference for the meter; the voltage on the lower part is measured by the meter w.r.t. the reference and displayed as resistance.

Comment: the text Im reading recommends to use the high resistance settings of an ohmmeter when checking diodes. what could be the reason for that?

Comment: @user16307 To ensure that the meter applies enough voltage to the diode to turn it on. (0.7 V for most silicon diodes, for instance.)

Comment: but in high settings most voltage drop will be in reference resistors according to your diagram. maybe the reason is to prevent damaging  the diode in lowest settings?

Comment: Actually if the meter uses a circuit similar to the one above, it will read nearly the same on any range -- perhaps about 10 % lower as you step down each range decade. However meters are slightly more complex than this -- there are protection circuits etc. and you will get variations. Some meters have a 'diode mode' which supplies about 1 mA and actually measures the voltage across the diode.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: It depends on the meter; most likely different meters will use different topologies (and digital auto-ranging meters likely add a LOT more complexity here).

A longer/more specific answer:
If you want to experimentally determine what changes when you adjust range on a specific meter (non auto-ranging):

1. Connect meter1 (the meter under test) to a resistor & test the resistance;
2. Now connect meter2 (another meter), in voltage-sense mode, across the resistor as well (or in series with the resistor in current-sense mode if that yjelds better readings);
3. Mark down the registered voltage, value of resistor, and range setting of meter1;
4. Change the range setting of meter1, then repeat step 3(do this for each range);
5. Grab a resistor of a different value and repeat steps 1-4 with it;
6. Use the data in the table you just made to make your necessary calibrations.

Comment: Additionally, he could measure the current the d.u.t. outputs into the 0-Ohm load of meter2 in current measurement mode.

Comment: the text Im reading recommends to use the high resistance settings of an ohmmeter when checking diodes. what could be the reason for that?

Comment: Diodes tend to display a "knee" voltage in their forard voltage/forward current charts. Below this "knee" voltage, the diode is insufficiently forward-biased to "turn on," displaying a _very_ high resistance. Above this voltage, the displayed resistance dropd off quickly as the additional current passed per measure of voltage goes up more exponentially than linearly. Thus, if tested below "knee" voltage, a diode will often appear as an "open circuit" regardless of current direction, but above this voltage you can test its forward/reverse function(s) correctly.